# setup phpmyadmin as subdomain on nginx amazon EC2 ubuntu server 17.04

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-server

I just got a domain ..and i am trying to setup the server..right i m trying to make a subdomain for it...but it's not working...i did add the domain on the amazon...but it's not working...

i have 2 files:
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/phpmyadmin

**default:**

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

                # With php7.0-cgi alone:
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php7.0-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

they are both in sites-enabled.
I try to access phpmyadmin.domain.com...says unable to connect...if i type the ip only...without anything else...it only gives me the welcome to nginx!

can you please help me?

Thank you in advance

**phpmyadmin:**

```
# phpMyAdmin subdomain
server {
    listen 80;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name phpmyadmin.domain.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add a A or CNAME record in route53 to point that server? Also it's best practice to get an Elastic IP if you're going to point directly to an ec2 instance.

Comment: yes i did ..A and CNAME

Comment: what is the output of `dig  phpmyadmin.domain.com` ? Also did you get the domain from Route 53 or another registrar? And if you did it takes 2 days to change the Name servers from one to Route 53, if you did that.